# Django - extend date template filter

Tags: django, django-templates

I am wondering if I can just define a variable like `LONG_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'D d F Y H:i'` in my settings and use it in template like:
`{{ my_date|date:"LONG_DATETIME_FORMAT" }}`? Can this be done without overwritting default `date` filter? Or should I write custom filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

> The format passed can be one of the predefined ones `DATE_FORMAT`, `DATETIME_FORMAT`, `SHORT_DATE_FORMAT` or `SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT`, or a custom format that uses the format specifiers shown in the table above. Note that predefined formats may vary depending on the current locale.

So feel free to set any of them in the settings

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'D d F Y H:i'

{{ my_date|date:"DATETIME_FORMAT" }}
```

Comment: So I need to assign my pattern to one of four predefined variables. No possibility to have multiple custom named pattern's variables that can be use by name in filter, right?

Comment: @krzyhub - Not really, if its restricted to a certain template you could always use a `with` tag to provide the format, but other than that your only other option is a custom template tag that you're trying to avoid

Comment: Do you mean something like that in templates:
{% with format=settings.LONG_DATETIME_FORMAT %} 
{{ my_date|date:format }}
{% endwith %}
?

Comment: @krzyhub - I was thinking `{% with format='D d F Y H:i' %}`, not sure if it would work though, I've never tried it (I assume it would)